# VueJS function return with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i have an array with objects like with id and name props.
In foreach i loop all objects and display the props in vue template.

```
<div class="column is-flex" v-for="(pic, index) in formdata.pictures" :key="index">
<p>{{pic.name}}</p>
<p>{{getPictureLocation(pic.id)}}</p>
</div>
```

```
getPictureLocation(id) {
      axios
        .post("/api/frontend/option/picture", {
          id: id
        })
        .then(response => {
          let data = response.data.items;
          if (data != null) {
            return data.name;
          }
        });
    }
```

In data.name is the right value like London or Berlin ...
The return value is not displayed in the html.
It shows always "".

What can i do to display the return value?

Comment: Have you tried using computed property?

Comment: link helped.. thanks